# must declare the scaler variable in sql

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables in MSSQL and try to make a simple join but even though I have experience in joins, I couldn't solve this problem.

```
declare @Table1 table
(
UserName nvarchar(4)
)
declare @Table2 table
(
UserName nvarchar(4),
UserSurname nvarchar(50)
)

SELECT * FROM @Table1 JOIN @Table2 ON @Table1.UserName = @Table2.UserName
```

When I run the query, I get an error like 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Table1".' and 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Table2".'
I join two tables with same attribute name and this must stay that way. Why I get an error like this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must alias the table variables like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 AS Table1
JOIN @Table2 AS Table2 ON Table1.UserName = Table2.UserName
```

Comment: Or enclose the table names used in column qualification since those don't conform to regular identifier naming rules (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx): `SELECT * FROM @Table1 JOIN @Table2 ON [@Table1].UserName = [@Table2].UserName`.